# Why click event gets fired after page ready event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

Please help me to understand why click event is being triggered on page ready event in my cordova app. As soon as page loads click event gets fired and if no country is selected still it tries to shoot mail on clicking "Login Help". Why?
In index.html

```
`<div class="app-login-email-help">
        <a id="EmailUsLink" class="app-login-email-help-text" href="#">
            <span>Login Help</span>
        </a>
</div>`

    $(document).on("pagecreate", function () {

        $x.page.login.init();

        $("#EmailUsLink").on('click', $x.page.login.ConstructLoginHelp);
         });
    });
```

In login.js

```
    ConstructLoginHelp: function () {
    var emailid = "APJ@gmail.com";
    var subjectLine = "Login Help";
    var emailBodyText = "Describe the login problem.";
    if($("#SelectCountry option:selected").val() != "undefined"){
        if ($("#SelectCountry option:selected").text()){
            if (!_.contains(['US', 'AU', 'CA', 'IN', 'MY', 'PH', 'SG', 'GB'], $('#SelectCountry').val())) {
                subjectLine = systemResources["LoginHelpSubjectLine".concat($("#SelectCountry option:selected").text())];
                emailBodyText = systemResources["LoginHelpEmailBody" + $("#SelectCountry option:selected").text()];
            } 
        }
        $x.page.login.elements.emailUsLink.attr('href', 'mailto:' + emailid + '?subject=' + subjectLine + '&body=' + emailBodyText);
    }
    else
        window.alert("Please Select Country");
}
```

There is a drop-down for which I haven't written the first element ("Select country") doesn't have a value.
I am also using underscore.js
Please ask for more information if needed.

Line by line execution shows as soon as the page starts loading ConstructLoginHelp s fired and it reaches to window.alert (which should not happen on page load). Now it is happening twice. And intrestingly link click is not working.

Comment: _"why click event is being triggered"_ - it isn't - your _function_ is being called, because that's what appending `()` to the function name does.

Comment: as for the why the "click" does not trigger the alert even though country has not selected yet, its because you are comparing it to a single space `" "`, try to change it to `""`, no space in between

Comment: removed the space still triggering the email.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your line:

```
$("#EmailUsLink").on('click',$x.page.login.ConstructLoginHelp());
```

By putting parentheses at the end of your function name, your are executing your function instead of giving it as a callback.
Remove the parentheses and it should be ok.

Comment: Thanks, removed parenthesis. But problem still exists. alert is showing before page is displayed and alert shows on no selection click.

Comment: Can you show us the code of `$x.page.login.init`? You're probably calling the ConstructLoginHelp function elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Get into the habit of reproducing the problem with a smaller code : [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Bad :

```js
$(document).on("ready", function () {
  $("a").on("click", sayHello());
});

function sayHello() {
  console.log("hello");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Email us</a>
```

Good :

```js
$(document).on("ready", function () {
  $("a").on("click", sayHello);
});

function sayHello() {
  console.log("hello");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Email us</a>
```